# Why is copying dictionaries so slow?

Tags: python, dictionary

I was solving one of Advent of Code questions and it turned out that my runtime was way too bad. I was using a dictionary with 1 million entries in it as a kind of "linked hashmap" where I can access item and it's value is the next item it's pointing to, so I had a linked list with O(1) lookup time. At some point I had to copy this dict, whch I did with simple

```
new_dict = dict(dictionary)
```

After playing with my code a bit, I removed this copying part and just ran the entire code on one dictionary. It suddenly sped up my runtime by orders of magnitude!
Why did this part of my code create such a bottleneck?

Comment: Copying any collection takes time proportional to its size.

Comment: Try `dictionary.copy()`.

Comment: Just for testing I (flat) copied a 10**8 items dictionary with multiple methods. All took around 3-5s which is acceptable IMHO.

Comment: It is acceptable of course, but I had to do 10 millions of those operations and suddenly it became a huge bottleneck. Everything else I did is O(1) and this was, as schwobaseggl said, O(n), so I guess that's why.

Comment: Thank you for help, I think that's it

Comment: How big is your dictionary? if its over 50, then ofcourse it takes time

Answer (score 2):

This is actually kinda interesting. Both `dictionary.copy()` and `dict(dictionary)` will make a shallow copy of the data in `dictionary`, however, one seems to run significantly faster.

I'm not exactly sure why this is, but I felt it would be interesting to post my findings. Perhaps someone can enlighten me in the comments:

```py
import timeit

data = {i: i for i in range(10000)}

print(timeit.timeit(lambda: data.copy(), number=20000))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: dict(data), number=20000))
```

```
0.8178407099999999
3.9644210609999995
```

If I had to guess I would say that `dict(dictionary)` is going over each key value pair to reconstruct the hash table, and `dictionary.copy()` is probably just copying the hash table and skipping a lot of the work required.

I would guess this is because the `dict(d)` builtin can be passed any object which implements the dictionary interface and that interface might not use the same hash table implementation, requiring that it be reconstructed when copying data.